# FFmpeg - Concatenate Audio - Video?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

How can i concatenate audio and video files by using ffmpeg?

I'm trying this but it does not work:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mkv -i new_audio.mp3 \
   -vcodec copy -acodec copy \
   -acodec copy \
   destination.mkv \
   -newaudio
```

Answer (score -1):

You can merge all streams from both input files using `-map input_index` as the following:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mkv -i new_audio.mp3 -map 0 -map 1 \
    -vcodec copy -acodec copy destination.mkv
```

To merge only selected streams use `-map input_index:stream_index`. For example, the following merges the first stream of the first input with the second input:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mkv -i new_audio.mp3 -map 0:0 -map 1 \
    -vcodec copy -acodec copy destination.mkv
```

Note, that indices start from zero.

Comment: my problem was the different length of audio and video. i fixed it by using the 'loop' parameter